# How do I get a JPopupMenu to "shadow" a component consistently

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a custom auto complete JTextField. I use the JPopupMenu to contain the selection.
I want to pop the JPopupMenu right under the JTextField using this method.

```
Rectangle r = textField.getBounds();
popup.show(textField, (int)(r.getX()), (int)(r.getY() + textField.getHeight));
popup.setVisible(true);
```

It works when I put the component in a simple JFrame. But when I put the component in a complex layout with JScrollPane. The location becomes random and inconsistent. I'd like the popupMenu to "shadow" the textField in any condition. How do I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: getBounds will return the location of the component relative to its parent. Instead, try using [getLocationOnScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup location is [relative to the parent component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29).

```
popup.show(textField, 0, textField.getHeight());
```

should place it right under the `textField`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But there is one thing. When the initial state of the JScrollPane's scrollbar is visible, the first popup location shifts a little. And it goes back to normal at the second popup. Do you know what causes this?

Comment: @William I don't know that. Certainly not without code to test. There are some subtle issues with popups, many of those system specific. They can be for instance slightly incorrectly sized at first time if the look & feel does something unusual, like uses a panel with a border where normally is none.